# How can you change the plug state of an HDMI port without plugging in a cable?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, hdmi

I want to change the state of HDMI to `hw.plugged` in software without actually plugging in a cable. It’s Android 2.3.2. I’m working on a kernel for a device and I want to see if HDMI broadcast is working, the plug state doesn’t seem to be working. So I want to spoof the plug state to bypass that issue.

Comment: I think you should be looking for a "dummy dongle"...

Comment: A dummy just does the same thing as a plug. I want to change the state in software from unplugged to plugged